# ColorFunction issues. Using different colors for different values of x

Tags: plotting, color

I am attempting to generate a plot for which the color changes for selected values of x as determined by a function. Below, is my best, unsuccessful attempt. The specific problem with this is that it worked only once for `x = 3Pi/4` but not for `x = Pi/4`. I am stumped, please help!

```
Plot[
 {Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi},
 ColorFunction -> Function[
   x,
   If[Abs[Cos[x]] > Abs[Sin[x]], Red, Blue]
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[x, If[Abs[Cos[x]] > Abs[Sin[x]], Red, Blue]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Comment: `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Abs[Cos[x]] - Abs[Sin[x]]], 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}, Mesh -> {{0}}]` is another way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `ColorFunctionScaling` to `False`, otherwise the `x` coordinate will be rescaled to lie between 0 and 1 before it is passed to the color function.

```
Plot[
 {Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi},
 ColorFunction -> Function[
   {x, y},
   If[
    Abs[Cos[x]] > Abs[Sin[x]],
    Red,
    Blue
    ]
   ],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]